# Creating UUID and UDID in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7

I want to create UUID, I have code below which can create UUID, how can I create UDID with multiple vendors same ID in iOS7?

```
+ (NSString*) stringWithNewUUID
{
    CFUUIDRef uuidObj = CFUUIDCreate(nil);
    NSString *newUUID = (NSString*)CFUUIDCreateString(nil, uuidObj);
    CFRelease(uuidObj);
    return newUUID;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us please why do you want to do that?

Comment: I have some business requirement

Comment: @SandeepKhade Why do you say it contains timestamp? [CFUUID documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Reference/CFUUIDRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFUUIDCreate) does not mention anything about timestamp.

Comment: CFUUID is generated using the unique identifier of the computer(MAC address) and the 100-nanosecond interval - so in that case why don't you just take the MAC address and create your own UUID?

Comment: I think he is referring to version 1 UUIDs (which include the MAC address and timestamp) vs. version 4 UUIDs (which are random).  If you look at the CFUUIDCreate() source code, it should use uuid_generate_random() to generate the UUID as long as you are linking on 10.4+.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have created a vendor ID and then saved it with keychain, which I am retaining for next time using `KeychainWrapper keychainStringFromMatchingIdentifier:...`

Comment: Did Apple approve this method?

Comment: Yes, If you do need the new UUID to last beyond app deletion and reinstall, the value could be stored in iOS’s keychain instead

Answer (score 5):

The `CFUUIDCreate` function produces a version 4 UUID which is taken entirely from a pseudo-random number generator.  There are no timestamps or MAC addresses embedded in this type of UUID. (That refers to the little-used version 1 flavour.) These are safe to use for nearly all applications.

Comment: Yep, see https://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-744/CFUUID.c  Technically, CFUUIDCreate() can create version 1 uuids, but the default is version 4 (just tested on iOS 7 and OS X 10.8)

Comment: Thanks I was looking to create UDID for device not for vendor ID

Answer (score 5):

This method returns random UUID in iOS 6 and above

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice]identifierForVendor]
```

Comment: Thanks Arun,I am looking to create unique identifier for my Device not for vendor

Comment: That isn't what it means.

-identifierForVendor

ID that is identical between apps from the same developer.

Comment: @CrossphireDevelopment: The `identifierForVendor` method does return different values in different devices regardless of the vendor. Apple Documentation: "The value of this property is the same for apps that come from the same vendor running on the same device. A different value is returned for apps on the same device that come from different vendors, and for apps on different devices regardless of vendor."

Comment: @ArminM I wasn't referring to multiple devices, just the current device.  It would be useless if it remained the same across devices, I was talking about consistency on the same device which would make it behave like a UDID.

Comment: Word of warning, identifierForVendor will change if ALL of that vendor's apps are removed from the device before installing another.

Answer (score 2):

The UUID that the code produces above does not have a recoverable time stamp in it. It's just a string that looks something like this: `E1D87006-7CD0-4E28-9768-624DA92F75D6`

Comment: yeah @claireware it's in form of string

Answer (score 0):

I followed Sandeep Khade's answer and made following code using [PDKeychainBindings](https://github.com/carlbrown/PDKeychainBindingsController/blob/master/PDKeychainBindingsController/PDKeychainBindings.m). It's same as using NSUserDefaults but it keeps identifier in keychain which saves data even when application is deleted.

```
+ (NSString *)uniqueVendor {

    PDKeychainBindings *keychain = [PDKeychainBindings sharedKeychainBindings];
    NSString *uniqueIdentifier = [keychain objectForKey:kKeyVendor];

    if (!uniqueIdentifier || !uniqueIdentifier.length) {

        NSUUID *udid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor];
        uniqueIdentifier = [udid UUIDString];
        [keychain setObject:uniqueIdentifier forKey:kKeyVendor];
    }

    return uniqueIdentifier;
}
```